# Active storage seed Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I want to seed my db with some instances containing active storage attachments, but i don't how i can do it. I tried some methods but not a success.

There is my Seed.

```
User.create(email: "test@ok.com", password: "okokok") if User.count.zero?

50.times do |i|
  temp = Template.create(
    title: Faker::Name.name,
    description: Faker::Lorem.paragraph(2),
    user: User.first,
    github_link: Faker::SiliconValley.url,
    category: rand(0...4)
  )
  puts Template.first.photo
  temp.photo.attach(Template.first.photo)
end
```

Thx for your help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's also in the documentation guide since a couple of days:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#attaching-file-io-objects

> Sometimes you need to attach a file that doesn’t arrive via an HTTP
>   request. For example, you may want to attach a file you generated on
>   disk or downloaded from a user-submitted URL. You may also want to
>   attach a fixture file in a model test. To do that, provide a Hash
>   containing at least an open IO object and a filename:

```
@message.image.attach(io: File.open('/path/to/file'), filename: 'file.pdf')
```

> When possible, provide a content type as well. Active Storage attempts
>   to determine a file’s content type from its data. It falls back to the
>   content type you provide if it can’t do that.

```
@message.image.attach(io: File.open('/path/to/file'), filename: 'file.pdf', content_type: 'application/pdf')
```

> If you don’t provide a content type and Active Storage can’t determine
>   the file’s content type automatically, it defaults to
>   application/octet-stream.

Comment: Note: '/path/to/file' includes the filename. The same filename as you again use in the filename keyword argument.

Answer (score 5):

Ok i found a solution, i post it for guys in the same situation:

```
temp.photo.attach(
    io: File.open('storage/3n/GG/3nGGV5K5ucYZDYSYojV8mDcr'),
    filename: 'file.png'
  )
```

If you have more easiest solutions share it ;)

Comment: you could accept your own answer and thus close the question so this question will be filtered in views that only show unanswered

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you found the path of the file you're opening?

Comment: It's your file path. This is for a seed. I don't really understand your question sorry.

Comment: I think I've been misunderstanding how this works. Are you opening the file path to your seed here, not the file path to the image your trying to attach?

Comment: I really wouldn't make sense to attach the seed file. I looks like you would want to attach the path to the image file.