# Seeding multiple image attachments from Amazon S3 in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I am trying to seed multiple image attachments to a model. I have been using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087938/active-storage-seed-rails) but I am still sort of stuck since what I aim to do differs a little since:

1. I am trying to attach multiple images to each object (which I seed) in the model
2. I want to retrieve these images from my S3 bucket and attach them to the objects (is this possible?)

Here's my seed.rb:

```
shirt = Item.create(name:"Basic Shirt",price:19.99)
skirt = Item.create(name:"Basic Skirt",price:29.99)
sweater = Item.create(name:"Basic Sweater",price:39.99)
kid_hood = Item.create(name:"Basic Kid Hoodie",price:19.99)

# somehow attach images here?
```

I am using the `aws-sdk-s3` gem in order to connect Active Storage to my S3 bucket. Please tell me if any additional files are needed for viewing. I will happily edit this post to include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveStorage work on plain byte streams, so you can download the file (using open-uri for instance) and assign the stream as the content of the attachment.

Assuming you have the following (adapt if different)

```rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo
end
```

you can have your seeds as:

```rb
require 'open-uri'

shirt = Item.create(name:"Basic Shirt",price:19.99)
shirt.photo.attach(io: open('your-s3-nonexpiring-url'), filename: 'foo.bar')

# ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: as of Ruby 3.0, you will need to call `URI.open` instead of `open`. See the reference to open-uri [here](https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges/3.0.html).